# Programming syntax - searching an array for a string matching input - visual basic

Tags: vb.net, arrays, search, match

Ok, I've combed the entire internet and can't find anything to help me here; I can't figure out the syntax for searching an array of stored words for a string matching an input string.

I understand the pseudocode of it, but I'm tripping up over what variables I need to put where, and how they should be formatted. If anyone here can help, it'd be greatly appreciated.

More than happy to provide more details should anyone request them.

Pseudocode;

```
Found = False

Loop through all the elements of the array

If current element = input, 

Then found = True

End of loop
```

Comment: Please use at least a programming language tag for your question. I've added `vba` for you, I assume that's correct for Visual Basic.

Comment: It says 'Visual Basic' in the title, but fair enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the internet you've searched :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eefw3xsy(v=vs.80).aspx 
And this is for vb6 : http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/searching-arrays-visual-basic-6